# Numerical sorting 2d array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am REALLY new at JS, and I am trying to sort this 2d array by the second value.  I swapped the 1st and 2nd values around so I can use .sort(), but since it is supposed to be a number I used function(a, b){return a - b}. It still doesn't work.

```
function orderListItemQuantity(){
for (i=0;i<items.length; i++){
    var temp = items[i][0];
    items[i][0] = items[i][1];
    items[i][1] = temp;
}
items.sort(function(a, b){return a - b});
for (i=0;i<items.length; i++){
    var temp = items[i][0];
    items[i][0] = items[i][1];
    items[i][1] = temp;
}
refreshList();
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Use the [brackets notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#Bracket_notation) to sort by the 2nd item (index 1) of each sub-array.

**Example:**

```js
var items = [[1, 3], [1, 1], [1, 2]];

items.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a[1] - b[1];
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(items));
```